# trigger button click from parent in user control (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `button` inside of my `MainWindow` and I want to trigger a method inside of my `UserControl` with it.

How can I achieve this?

MAIN WINDOW:

```
<Grid>
   <local:UserControl1></local:UserControl1>
   <Button Click="btn_click"></Button>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Simpliest and dirtiest way: Give th UserControl a name: x:Name="Uc1" and in your button click even: Uc1.Method();

Comment: Why is this method in a piece of ui at all? You should take a look at mvvm, commands and abstract processing data from displaying data.

Answer (score -1):

We considering you have a user controll named X

The first code will change stuff directly without instance of user controll

```
btn_click(){
     x MyUserControl = (x)System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows.
     OfType<UserControl>().FirstOrDefault();
     x. your code....   ;         
 
}
```

This will first get an instance of user control then it changes stuff

```
btn_click(){
          x myInstanceUserControl = new x();
             x. your code....       ;
 
}
```

finally with this code you can set location of your UserControl

```
 Grid.SetColumn(x, int);
         Grid.SetRow(x, int); // add to next row
         Grid.SetColumnSpan(x, int);
         MainGrid.Children.Add(x);
```